# Showing the amount that has been rounded off instead of only the after-round off value c#

Tags: c#

im sorry if it will be confusing as the title speaks, but i will explain in details of what i need. sorry for troubling as i am still a newbie in c#.
here, lets say:

```
decimal value = 40.23;
decimal total = Math.Round(value * 20.0m, 0) / 20.0m;
roundingbox.Text = total.ToString("f2");
```

the output given will be 40.25 without fail. 
However, im not sure if it is possible to do something like this, e.g: 
[round off amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVm4C.jpg)

please let me know as i have been stuck here for quite some time in my progress to create a pos system. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decimal difference = value - total;` should give you what you want, no?

Comment: omg seriously i was so dumb to not realising it!! im so sorry but thank you!